# Generalization of any() function with switchable default parameter for empty iterables

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

I have some use-cases where I want the behaviour of the build-in `any()` function to be slightly different, namely to return `True` if the iterable is empty.

Therefore I came up with the following override:

```
_any = any  # Alias built-in any.


def any(iterable, *, default=False):
    """Generalization of the built-in any() function."""

    if not default:
        return _any(iterable)

    count = 0

    for count, item in enumerate(iterable, start=1):
        if item:
            return True

    return count == 0
```

The code I used to test this is:

```
EMPTY_TUPLE = ()
FALSEY_TUPLE = (False, None, 0, '')
TRUEY_TUPLE = (False, None, 1, '')


def empty_iterables():
    """Yields empty iterables."""

    yield list(EMPTY_TUPLE)
    yield EMPTY_TUPLE
    yield {item: item for item in EMPTY_TUPLE}
    yield set(EMPTY_TUPLE)
    yield (i for i in EMPTY_TUPLE)


def falsey_iterables():
    """Yields iterables that any() should assert as False."""

    yield list(FALSEY_TUPLE)
    yield FALSEY_TUPLE
    yield {item: item for item in FALSEY_TUPLE}
    yield set(FALSEY_TUPLE)
    yield (i for i in FALSEY_TUPLE)


def truey_iterables():
    """Yields iterables that any() should assert as True."""

    yield list(TRUEY_TUPLE)
    yield TRUEY_TUPLE
    yield {item: item for item in TRUEY_TUPLE}
    yield set(TRUEY_TUPLE)
    yield (i for i in TRUEY_TUPLE)


def test():
    """Tests the custom any() function."""

    # Built-in behaviour.
    for iterable in empty_iterables():
        assert any(iterable) is False

    for iterable in falsey_iterables():
        assert any(iterable) is False

    for iterable in truey_iterables():
        assert any(iterable) is True

    # Custom behaviour.
    for iterable in empty_iterables():
        assert any(iterable, default=True) is True

    for iterable in falsey_iterables():
        assert any(iterable, default=True) is False

    for iterable in truey_iterables():
        assert any(iterable, default=True) is True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

I wonder whether there's a more elegant way to implement the custom `any()` function with the aforementioned behaviour.

**Use case**

I have a custom monitoring system, that determines the state of a system using check records from a MariaDB database. I use peewee as an ORM:

```
def check_customer_system(system):
    """Returns the customer online check for the respective system."""

    end = datetime.now()
    start = end - CUSTOMER_INTERVAL
    condition = OnlineCheck.system == system
    condition &= OnlineCheck.timestamp >= start
    condition &= OnlineCheck.timestamp <= end
    query = OnlineCheck.select().where(condition)

    if query:
        return any(online_check.online for online_check in query)

    raise NotChecked(system, OnlineCheck)
```

In the current implementation, I need to check, whether the amount of records in the query in non-empty by doing `if query:`.
However, this will execute the query an load all records into RAM, which I want to avoid. Peewee has the optional `.iterator()` method on queries, which will return an iterator, that will not load all records into RAM at once. However, if I use that, `if query:` will always be `True` since it's testing the truth value of a generator object then.
Hence, I came up with the idea to implement a function, that returns `True` if any value of an iterable is `True` or the iterable is empty.

And I just realized that this is indeed an XY-Problem, since I'd loose the ability to distinguish between a checked and a non-checked system.
Thanks @Eric Duminil.

Comment: any reason for `start=1`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 To distinguish empty input from single-element input.

Comment: You've misspelt [truthy](https://www.lexico.com/definition/truthy).

Comment: It looks like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). We shouldn't be reviewing this code, because its specs are broken, and no implementation can save it. We should be looking at the code using your custom `any`, to see how the logic can be modified.

Comment: @EricDuminil I clarified the use case.

Comment: @RichardNeumann: Interesting, thanks. The question now becomes completely different, though. I'm not sure if it should be a new question, now that you've already got long answers.

Comment: @EricDuminil Hmm, what did you mean with the specs being broken?

Comment: @superbrain `any` is a well defined, very important mathematical concept. You cannot simply redefine it and make it return wrong results for empty sets. If you do, you get contradictory results really fast, and your code will become buggy in many unexpected places. It doesn't result from a wrong implementation, but from the wrong specs.

Comment: @EricDuminil Ah, ok. I thought you meant the spec itself being broken somehow, not the spec disagreeing with something else (the normal `any`). I agree as written it's bad/wrong (said so in my answer), but I think the problem is just the name, not the behavior. So I'd say their implementation of the latter is fit for review (particularly because the question is about "a more elegant way to implement [...] the aforementioned behaviour").

Comment: What is `online_check.online`? Does it use custom python logic, or could it be written as an SQL query too?

Comment: It's a boolean field of a record.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I really think this is a bad idea. A function called `any` returning `True` if there not only isn't anything *true* but even not anything *at all*... that's just wrong. It sure isn't a "generalization". Shadowing the built-in is not a good idea, either. Maybe just call yours `any_or_empty` (without a default)?

For the emptiness check, the counting seems like overkill and I think a Boolean is clearer (and probably faster, due to not going through `enumerate`):

```
    empty = True

    for item in iterable:
        if item:
            return True
        empty = False

    return empty
```

Or with a sentinel, to get rid of the assignment in the loop:

```
    item = sentinel = object()

    for item in iterable:
        if item:
            return True

    return item is sentinel
```

For best speed, you could just handle the first item yourself and then let the built-in handle the rest:

```
def any(iterable, *, default=False):
    """Modification of the built-in any() function."""

    it = iter(iterable)
    sentinel = object()
    first = next(it, sentinel)
    if first is sentinel:
        return default
    return bool(first) or _any(it)
```

Your test code uses the words "truey" and "falsey". That's not Python terminology. See the Python docs, [you'll never find those words](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.python.org+%22truey%22+OR+%22falsey%22). It's true and false, as you can for example see at [`if`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if), [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans) and [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

The name `falsey_iterables` is ambiguous if not misleading, as it doesn't yield any false iterables. They're all true. They just don't *contain* anything true. I'd suggest `iterables_without_trues`. And `iterables_with_true` instead of `truey_iterables` for consistency.

Did you have this idea because `next`, `min` and `max` offer a `default` parameter? In their cases it makes sense, as they rather *need* non-empty inputs. And meaningful defaults are possible there, for example `min` with `default=float('inf')` could be a useful default for the code using the result.

Comment: Thanks for the review. Also thanks for the review of the testing code, though it was not, what this review was about. I'll definitely change the name of the custom `any()`, since on second thought, a function called "any" should indeed never return `True` on an empty input.

Comment: And now I'm curious why someone voted that "This answer is not useful"...

Comment: You've got a recursive implementation.  If you have an iterable of 100 false values, you'll use 100 stack frames, pealing off one value from the head of `iterable` each time.  You probably wanted to call `_any(it)`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Ah yes, thanks. As stated, the intention was to "let the built-in handle the rest". Fixed. Proves the point that we shouldn't shadow the built-in :-)

Comment: Not overriding a core builtin and handing over the non-empty case to the builtin are both excellent suggestions for maintainability. Fewer surprises (for anyone already familiar with `any`) and less code overall.

Answer (score 9):

## Any and All

If you are going to override `any(...)` to return a custom result when given an empty iterable, you should also override `all(...)` to return a custom result as well, for consistency.

## Detecting the Empty Iterable

This code:

```
    count = 0

    for count, item in enumerate(iterable, start=1):
        if item:
            return True

    return count == 0
```

relies on `count` being reassigned to a non-zero value by the `for count ... in enumerable(..., start=1)` loop.  This has two inefficiencies.  First, it is repeatedly assigning values to `count`.  Second, it creates and abandons `int` objects (once it has gone beyond the range of interned `int` values), which are only used for their "non equality to zero".  A flag could eliminate this second inefficiency:

```
    is_empty = True

    for item in iterable:
        if item:
            return True
        is_empty = False

    return is_empty
```

But this still leaves the first inefficiency: repeated assignments to `is_empty`.

Better would be to extract the first value from the iterable.  If that fails, then the iterable was empty.

```
_any = any
_all = all

def any(iterable, *, default=False):
    """Generalization of the built-in any() function."""

    if not isinstance(default, bool):
        raise TypeError("Default must be a boolean value")

    try:
        it = iter(iterable)
        return bool(next(it)) or _any(it)

    except StopIteration:
        return default


def all(iterable, *, default=True):
    """Generalization of the built-in all() function."""

    if not isinstance(default, bool):
        raise TypeError("Default must be a boolean value")

    try:
        it = iter(iterable)
        return bool(next(it)) and _all(it)

    except StopIteration:
        return default
```

## Testing

`empty_iterables()`, `falsey_iterables()` and `truey_iterables()` is confusing.  It took me a while to determine that you were creating a series of different kinds of test iterables: a `list`, a `tuple`, a `dict`, a `set`, and a generator expression.  Moreover, it is code duplications.  All 3 functions are generating the same things, just with different values.

This would be clearer:

```
from typing import Iterable, Any

def test_iterables_of(*values: Any) -> Iterable[Iterable[Any]]:
    """
    Generate various types of collections of the given values.

    Returns a list, tuple, dictionary, set, and generator expression,
    each containing all of the values.
    """

    yield list(values)
    yield tuple(values)
    yield dict((val, val) for val in values)
    yield set(values)
    yield (val for val in values)  # Generator
```

And you could use like:

```
    for iterable in test_iterables_of():
        assert any(iterable, default=True) is True

    for iterable in test_iterables_of(False, None, 0, ''):
        assert any(iterable, default=True) is False
```

### Dictionary Key 0 / False

Just a note: Your dictionaries of `FALSEY_TUPLE` values have only 3 entries, not 4, because the key `False` and the key `0` are actually the same key.

Comment: I'd say there was another inefficiency, the `enumerate` iterator being another layer on top of the underlying iterator (creating the ints is part of that, but not all). The assignment in the loop can btw be avoided rather easily, although I didn't think of it at first, either :-) (just added that to my answer)

Comment: If `any` is now broken, the solution isn't to break `all` too for consistency, is it?

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm not sure why you feel this is "breaking" `any`.  The built-in function doesn't support keyword arguments; with no `default=` argument, the upgraded function behaves the same way as the built-in function.  If this was submitted as a PEP to the design team, they might very well consider adding the `default` keyword to `any()` and `all()`.  Where these upgrades can be "break" is forward compatibility; if other keyword arguments were added in Python 3.9 or Python 4.x, this upgrade would, break those.  I agree the question update does make this whole mess an XY-Problem.

Comment: @AJNeufeld The way I see it, an `any` function which returns `True` for an empty set is broken *by design*, even with an extra argument, even if the implementation is correct and if it doesn't break backward compatibility. The corresponding `all`, should, I guess, return `False` for empty collections, which would contradict [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), among others. No amount of documentation could save the surprising bugs coming out of this design.

Comment: @EricDuminil The built-in `all(())` returns `True`.  Writing `all((), default=True)` is clearer, because the "surprising" value is called out in the function arguments, instead of hidden away is some documentation.  This default would actually be very useful in the real world.  Cell-phone transmit power control is approximately `turn_power_down = any(received_power_down_flags, default=True)`.  If any base station is saying "turn down your power", the cell phone turns power down ... but if it can't hear any base station flags, it still must turn its power down so it doesn't become a jammer.

Comment: We might have to agree to disagree, then. `all(())` returning `True` is the expected value. The surprising value would be `False`, and I don't see how it would be clear for `all((), default=True)` to return `False`. Your cell phone power example is interesting, but a better function name should be chosen (`any_or_empty` was proposed in another answer, so a modified `all` could be called `all_but_not_empty`). ∃ and ∀ are so important and ubiquitous in math, if you insist on redefining them, you might as well say that 1 = 2.

Answer (score 7):

#### Benchmarks and a faster solution

Code including the solutions at the end. And note I also have an image further down that might be worth checking out before/while reading.

**Empty iterable**

First an empty iterable, as that's what motivated the question in the first place, and perhaps that also suggests that that happens non-negligibly often in what the OP is doing:

```
iterable = []   number = 2,000,000 = how often each function is run
1.26  1.25  1.23  original
0.65  0.65  0.65  loop_bool
0.86  0.86  0.86  loop_sentinel
1.00  1.00  1.01  default_and_builtin
1.30  1.33  1.32  try_and_builtin
0.73  0.72  0.75  for_and_builtin
0.74  0.73  0.75  for_and_builtin2
```

The two simpler loop solutions are faster than the original, as they save the cost of `enumerate` creation. Slowest is the solution with `try`, as "[catching an exception is expensive](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions)". The other solution using the built-in `any` instead of looping, the one trying `next` with a default and then checking that, is faster, but still faster is the `for_and_builtin` solution:

```
def any(iterable, *, default=False):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for first in it:
        return bool(first) or _any(it)
    return default
```

Its slightly less pretty variant `for_and_builtin2` is equally fast, as the difference is only in the loop body, which doesn't come into play yet:

```
def any(iterable, *, default=False):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for first in it:
        return True if first else _any(it)
    return default
```

**One-element iterables**

```
iterable = [False]  number = 2,000,000  iterable = [True]
 1.35  1.36  1.38       original        1.26  1.24  1.24 
 0.73  0.75  0.73       loop_bool       0.70  0.69  0.68 
 0.93  0.95  0.93      loop_sentinel    0.87  0.89  0.88 
 1.34  1.36  1.36  default_and_builtin  1.22  1.20  1.21 
 1.12  1.13  1.11    try_and_builtin    1.02  0.99  0.99 
 1.05  1.07  1.07    for_and_builtin    0.95  0.95  0.95 
 0.87  0.89  0.88    for_and_builtin2   0.79  0.76  0.79
```

All got slower, except `try_and_builtin`, which got *faster* since it doesn't pay the heavy price of catching an exception anymore. Still slightly slower than `for_and_builtin`, though. And `for_and_builtin2` was impacted far less and remains the second-fastest solution.

**Two elements**

Not much change here.

```
 [False, False]    number = 2,000,000   [False, True]  
1.42  1.43  1.42       original        1.35  1.32  1.39
0.77  0.78  0.79       loop_bool       0.74  0.77  0.75
0.96  0.92  0.95     loop_sentinel     0.91  0.92  0.90
1.32  1.30  1.32  default_and_builtin  1.29  1.32  1.35
1.11  1.11  1.08    try_and_builtin    1.09  1.10  1.09
1.06  1.03  1.06    for_and_builtin    1.05  1.06  1.05
0.91  0.89  0.86    for_and_builtin2   0.86  0.88  0.86
```

**Long iterables**

At ten elements, the faster loop solutions are still competitive, but in the long runs, they become a lot slower than the solutions making the built-in `any` do the hard work. Of the three loop solutions, `loop_sentinel` becomes the fastest, as it has the least to do in each iteration. The three built-in users become equally fast.

```
iterable = [False] * 10**1    number = 2,000,000
2.03  2.02  2.02  original
1.25  1.25  1.24  loop_bool
1.30  1.26  1.26  loop_sentinel
1.43  1.42  1.37  default_and_builtin
1.19  1.17  1.19  try_and_builtin
1.18  1.15  1.13  for_and_builtin
0.96  0.96  0.99  for_and_builtin2

iterable = [False] * 10**2    number = 200,000
0.86  0.85  0.86  original
0.59  0.59  0.59  loop_bool
0.41  0.40  0.40  loop_sentinel
0.21  0.21  0.21  default_and_builtin
0.19  0.19  0.19  try_and_builtin
0.18  0.19  0.19  for_and_builtin
0.17  0.16  0.17  for_and_builtin2

iterable = [False] * 10**3    number = 20,000
0.93  0.93  0.93  original
0.52  0.51  0.53  loop_bool
0.32  0.32  0.32  loop_sentinel
0.09  0.09  0.09  default_and_builtin
0.09  0.09  0.09  try_and_builtin
0.09  0.09  0.09  for_and_builtin
0.09  0.09  0.09  for_and_builtin2

iterable = [False] * 10**6    number = 20
1.01  0.99  1.01  original
0.53  0.54  0.51  loop_bool
0.32  0.32  0.32  loop_sentinel
0.08  0.08  0.08  default_and_builtin
0.08  0.08  0.08  try_and_builtin
0.08  0.08  0.08  for_and_builtin
0.08  0.08  0.08  for_and_builtin2
```

Then again, how likely does the iterable have a million false elements but not a single true element? Probably rather unlikely. If we assume that every element has a 50% chance to be true, then there's only a one-in-a-million chance that there's no true element in the first 20 elements (if the iterable even is that long). So let's have a better look at `[False] * n` for `n` from 0 to 20:

[image: closer look at 0 to 20 elements]

Full benchmark code (for the textual outputs):

```
from timeit import repeat
from functools import partial

_any = any  # Alias built-in any.

def original(iterable, *, default=False):
    if not default:
        return _any(iterable)
    count = 0
    for count, item in enumerate(iterable, start=1):
        if item:
            return True
    return count == 0

def loop_bool(iterable, *, default=False):
    if not default:
        return _any(iterable)
    empty = True
    for item in iterable:
        if item:
            return True
        empty = False
    return empty

def loop_sentinel(iterable, *, default=False):
    if not default:
        return _any(iterable)
    item = sentinel = object()
    for item in iterable:
        if item:
            return True
    return item is sentinel

def default_and_builtin(iterable, *, default=False):
    it = iter(iterable)
    sentinel = object()
    first = next(it, sentinel)
    if first is sentinel:
        return default
    return bool(first) or _any(it)

def try_and_builtin(iterable, *, default=False):
    try:
        it = iter(iterable)
        return bool(next(it)) or _any(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return default

def for_and_builtin(iterable, *, default=False):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for first in it:
        return bool(first) or _any(it)
    return default

def for_and_builtin2(iterable, *, default=False):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for first in it:
        return True if first else _any(it)
    return default

funcs = original, loop_bool, loop_sentinel, default_and_builtin, try_and_builtin, for_and_builtin, for_and_builtin2

num = 2 * 10**6
tests = [
    ('[]', num),
    ('[False]', num),
    ('[True]', num),
    ('[False, False]', num),
    ('[False, True]', num),
    ('[False] * 10**1', num // 10**0),
    ('[False] * 10**2', num // 10**1),
    ('[False] * 10**3', num // 10**2),
    ('[False] * 10**6', num // 10**5),
    ]

for iterable, number in tests:
    print('iterable =', iterable, f'   {number = :,}')
    iterable = eval(iterable)
    times = [[] for _ in funcs]
    for _ in range(3):
        for func, ts in zip(funcs, times):
            t = min(repeat(partial(func, iterable, default=True), number=number))
            ts.append(t)
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, times):
        print(*('%.2f' % t for t in ts), func.__name__, sep='  ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: Since you provided more information about your actual problem, this answer will be very different to the already existing answers. Their pieces of advice are still valid : you really shouldn't break `any()`.

## Your actual problem

> However, this will execute the query an load all records into RAM, which I want to avoid

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31715766/6419007), you could simply call Peewee's [`query.exists()`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=exists#SelectBase.exists) to know if there's at least one record returned by this query.

The [source code](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/peewee.py#L2178) makes it clear it retrieves at most 1 record from the DB, and only returns a boolean:

```
@database_required
def exists(self, database):
    clone = self.columns(SQL('1'))
    clone._limit = 1
    clone._offset = None
    return bool(clone.scalar())
```

I tried a small example on my laptop:

```
query = Movie.select().where((Movie.year > 1950) & (Movie.year < 1960))
query.exists()
```

Here's the corresponding Postgres log (please notice `LIMIT 1`):

> SELECT 1 FROM "movies" AS "t1" WHERE (("t1"."year" > 1950) AND ("t1"."year" < 1960)) LIMIT 1

Asking for the number of corresponding records with `query.count()` also doesn't retrieve every row:

> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM "movies" AS "t1" WHERE (("t1"."year" > 1950) AND ("t1"."year" < 1960))) AS "_wrapped"

Only when I iterate over every row does peewee send a complete query:

```
for movie in query:
    print(movie.title)
```

> SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."title", "t1"."imdb_id", "t1"."year", "t1"."seen", "t1"."rating" FROM "movies" AS "t1" WHERE (("t1"."year" > 1950) AND ("t1"."year" < 1960))